# Ember how to call computed property with arguements

Tags: ember.js, properties, coffeescript, call

```
checked: ((key, value) ->
        selected = @get 'controllers.a.selected'
        a = @get 'model'
        if arguments.length > 1
          if value
            selected.addObject a
          else
            selected.removeObject a

        return selected.contains a
      ).property('controllers.a.selected.length')
```

Now I am trying to call the checked property.
I tried to use `@controller.get('checked')`,
but how do I pass `key, value` arguments so that I can test the property. 
I do not know how to call it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I hate setting computed properties, I think it's a terrible pattern, but here's how it's done `@controller.set('checked', 'foo')`.

http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties